# Extracting specific keys and their values from json column

Tags: r, json

I have a column (called remarks) in a data frame containing data of this format. Each row has data that is of this format.

```
[{"Market": "test1", "Status": "FILLED", "Account": "", "Comment": "", "FilledPrice": 8026.7}]
```

Is there a way for me to extract out the values by calling the key. say I want the value of "Market" and it gives me "test1" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [library(jqr)](https://github.com/ropensci/jqr) to manipulate and access JSON strings

```
library(jqr)

js <- '[{"Market": "test1", "Status": "FILLED", "Account": "", "Comment": "", "FilledPrice": 8026.7}]'

jqr::jq(js, ".[].Market")
# "test1"
```

Comment: the output from this returns double quotes. is there a way to remove the double quotes?